# How to Return Records Equal to a Specific Percentage of an Aggregate in Transact-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

My requirement is to provide a random sample of claims that comprise 2.5% of the total amount paid and also comprise 2.5% of total claims for a given population.  The goal is to deliver records in a report that meet both criteria.  My staging table is defined as follows:

```
[RecordId] UniqueIdentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEWID()
,ClaimNO varchar(50)
,Company_ID varchar(10)
,HPCode varchar(10)
,FinancialResponsibility varchar(30)
,ProviderType varchar(50)
,DateOfService date
,DatePaid date
,ClaimType varchar(50)
,TotalBilled numeric(11,2)
,TotalPaid numeric(11,2)
,ProcessorType varchar(100)
```

I've already built the logic to return 2.5% of the total number of claims but need guidance in how best to ensure both criterion are met.

Here's what I've tried thus far:

```
with cteTotals as (
Select Count(*) as TotalClaims, sum(TotalPaid) as TotalPaid, sum(TotalPaid) * .025 as PaidSampleAmount
from [Z_Monthly_Quality_Review]
),

ctePopulation as (
    Select *
    from [Z_Monthly_Quality_Review]
),

cteSampleRows as (  
    select TOP 2.5 PERCENT NEWID() RandomID, RecordID, ClaimNo, HPCode, FinancialResponsibility, ProviderType, ProcessorType, 
    Format(DateOfService, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as DateOfService, Format(DatePaid, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as DatePaid, ClaimType, TotalBilled, TotalPaid  
    from [Z_Monthly_Quality_Review]  
    order by NEWID()
    ),

cteSamplePaid as (
    Select Top 2.5 PERCENT NEWID() RandomID, RecordID, ClaimNo, HPCode, FinancialResponsibility, ProviderType, ProcessorType,
    Format(DateOfService, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as DateOfService, Format(DatePaid, 'MM/dd/yyyy') as DatePaid, ClaimType, TotalBilled, TotalPaid  
    from [Z_Monthly_Quality_Review] mqr
    inner join ctePopulation cte on mqr.ClaimNo = cte.ClaimNO
    order by NEWID()
)
```

Since both criterion must be satisfied, how should I structure both CTEs to ensure this?  In my cteSamplePaid, how do I ensure that the sum of total paid equals 2.5% of the total population?  Would this be accomplished with a Having clause?  The end result will be displayed to my business users via SQL Server Reporting Services.  Ideally, I would want to provide them with 1 sample that meets both criteria.  If that's not possible, how do I randomly sample claims from both criterion?

Comment: Using `union` would give you 5% of the rows, less any eliminated for being duplicates. (Use `union all` to avoid removing duplicates.) Do you really need _one_ set of rows that meet _both_ criteria at the same time? What if that isn't possible? How close do the sums need to be? DDL, sample data and expected results would help clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think there is a guaranteed way it will add up to 2.5% of the total. There's no guarantee results and the performance would be very poor as it you would essentially have to brute force every possible combination of rows. A way to get very close to your goal would be to use return rows that add up to an acceptable margin of error.

Since no sample data was provided, I just used AdventureWorks2017 (downloaded from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=ssms))

```
USE AdventureWorks2017 
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SalesData
SELECT SalesOrderID AS ID,TotalDue
INTO #SalesData
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader

Declare @DesiredPercentage Numeric(10,3) = .025 /*Desired sum percentage of total rows*/
        ,@AcceptableMargin Numeric(10,3) = .01 /*Random row total can be plus or minus this percentage of the desired sum*/
DECLARE @DesiredSum Numeric(16,2) =  @DesiredPercentage *(SELECT SUM(TotalDue) FROM #SalesData)

/*For loop*/
DECLARE @RowNum INT
    ,@LoopCounter INT = 1
    
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #RandomData
    SELECT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY B.RandID),A.*,RunningTotal = SUM(TotalDue) OVER (ORDER BY B.RandID)
    INTO #RandomData
    FROM #SalesData AS A
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT RandID = NEWID()) AS B
    WHERE TotalDue < @DesiredSum /*If single row bigger than desired sum, then filter it out*/
    ORDER BY B.RandID

    SELECT Top(1) @RowNum = RowNum
    FROM #RandomData AS A
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT DeltaFromDesiredSum = ABS(RunningTotal-@DesiredSum)) AS B
    WHERE RunningTotal BETWEEN @DesiredSum *(1-@AcceptableMargin) AND @DesiredSum *(1+@AcceptableMargin)
    ORDER BY DeltaFromDesiredSum

    IF (@RowNum IS NOT NULL)
        BREAK;

    IF (@LoopCounter >=100) /*Prevents infinite loops*/
        THROW 59194,'Result unable to be generated in 100 tries. Recommend expanding acceptable margin',1;

    SET @LoopCounter +=1;
END

SELECT *
FROM #RandomData
WHERE RowNum <= @RowNum

SELECT RandomRowTotal = SUM(TotalDue)
    ,DesiredSum = @DesiredSum
    ,PercentageFromDesiredSum = Concat(Cast(Round(100*(1-SUM(TotalDue)/@DesiredSum),2) as Float),'%')
FROM #RandomData
WHERE RowNum <= @RowNum
```